# Angular 7 esperando serviço responder para continuar

Tags: angular, angular-5, angular-7

Boa tarde, galera, possuo dois métodos, como faço para esperar um método que está chamando um serviço externo responder para continuar a execução do método que chamou esse método? 
Exemplo:

```
salvarUsuario(){
this.usuario = formUsuario.value();
this.pegarEndereco(this.usuario.cep);
this.usuarioService.salvar().subscribe();
}

pegarEndereco(cep: string){
this.cepService.buscarPorCep(cep).subscribe((response: any) => {
this.usuario.endereco = response;
});
}
```

Nesse caso, eu só quero continuar a execução após o pegarEndereço() responder.

**Obs: não queria fazer a chamada dentro do subscribe do cepService.buscarPorCep(cep)**

Comment: você tem que criar um observable, de uma lida: https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: Tem que fazer dentro do subscribe pq é assincrono

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um "subscribe" na função "pegarEndereço" dentro da salvarUsuario.

```
salvarUsuario(){
  this.usuario = formUsuario.value();
  this.pegarEndereco(this.usuario.cep).subscribe(success -> {
         this.usuarioService.salvar().subscribe();
  }, error -> {
         fazerAlgumaCoisa();
  });

}

pegarEndereco: any(cep: string){
  return this.cepService.buscarPorCep(cep);
}
```